# Bootstrap thumbnail alignment (horizontal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added the thumbnail class to my thumbnails div, which had the intended effect. However, some of the thumbnails were smaller in size than the others. I wanted them to have the same height so I gave each thumbnail a height of 210px, thinking that would now appear the same all aligned horizontally in a line. However, setting the height had the strange effect of making the smaller thumbnails jut out of the alignment by extending below. I tried solving this by setting the css property of `top: 0px;` on each thumbnail, but that did not make any difference. How can I get all my thumbnails to be the same height AND be perfectly aligned horizontally?

Comment: please give link or jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

The problem was eventually solved by adding style element `overflow: hidden;` to the thumbnail class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, did you try putting each image in its own div class for columns? If you are at all thinking of responsive design (which is why one typically uses bootstrap) this might help you get them to align extremely quickly and easily.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html, take a look at the live fluid grid part.